# Solving a nonhomogeneous recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

How does one solve a recurrence relation of the kind
$u_{k+1} = u_k + u_{k-1} + a \cdot \cos(\omega k)$
for arbitrary $a > 0$ and $\omega > 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us take the Z transform from both sides. One can conveniently use the properties of the Z-transform listed in Wikipedia, as well as table of common Z-transforms. We get:

$$z \psi= \psi +z^{-1} \psi +a \frac{1-z^{-1} \cos(\omega)}{1- 2 z^{-1}  cos(\omega) +z^{-2}}  $$
This can be recast as
$$  \psi= a \frac{1-z^{-1} \cos(\omega)}{\bigg[1- 2 z^{-1}  cos(\omega) +z^{-2}\bigg] \big(z-1-z^{-1} \big) }  $$
You can easily expand this in powers of $z^{-1}$. We have: 
$$
\psi= \frac{a}{z}+a \frac{1+\cos(\omega)}{z^2}
+ a \frac{1+\cos(\omega)+2 \cos^2(\omega)}{z^3}
+ a \frac{2-\cos(\omega)+2 \cos^2(\omega)+4 \cos^2(\omega)}{z^4}+\ldots
$$
Using straightforward trigonometric  identities,  we  observe that the coefficient of $z^{-k}$, which is $u_k$, is given by
$$u_k =a \sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1} F_{k-\ell} \cos\big(\omega \ell \big),
$$
where $F_j$ denotes the j-th Fibonacci number: 
$$
F_1=1, F_2=1, F_3= 2, F_4= 3, F_5 = 5, F_6= 8 \ldots
$$

Answer (score 2):

I would treat is
as the real part of
$u_{k+1} 
= u_k + u_{k-1} + a e^{i\omega k}
= u_k + u_{k-1} + a c^k
$
(where
$c 
= e^{i \omega}
$),
solve this,
and then take the
real part of the solution.

Comment: For sure, the idea is very good but the problem turns to be a monster !!

Comment: My specialty: executive mathematics!